# Mobile Chrome flickering when using scroll snap

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, chrome-for-android, scroll-snap

I am experiencing a weird glitch on Chrome for mobile: I have a webpage using scroll snap and if I scroll down the whole chrome browser would flicker, including the address bar! I don't know why. It works perfectly on other browsers so it's not a code issue, I think. Here's a gif with the problem I'm talking about. [Glitch GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpChR.gif)

Comment: did you get any insight on the cause? Or even better did you find a solution? I'm having a similar problem but in a chrome-based webview on Android devices.

Comment: Nope, I changed the website so that it wouldn't use scroll snap.